# Count number of attributes of a class

Tags: python, django, class, attributes, attr

I want to make a fully dynamic table which adjusts its self number of columns depending on which type of object I'm passing in the view.

What I tried is:

```
from Food.models import Food


for field in Food:
    # Count how many fields do my class Food has.
```

But PyCharm is showing the following error:

```
Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'Type[Food]' instead.
```

Pretty obvious since it's not an actual initialized object. But how can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Food._meta.fields` to get a list of fields on the model.

Comment: It worked! Any way to make the same with the labels of a form's fields? I know Form.base_fields but it returns a collection of strings with the name of fields, I'd like to get their labels instead.

Comment: I'd recommend installing IPython locally, opening up a shell, instantiating a form and using the Tab auto-complete functionality to poke around the class. Or you can review Django's code on Github to see what's all there.